# bootstrap-datepicker does not function at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

My datetimepicker is not working I don't know what exactly is the problem.
Please tell me if I have missed to include any css or script tags.

I am using http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker8').datetimepicker({
                icons: {
                    time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                    date: "fa fa-calendar",
                    up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                    down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2           form-control-label">D.O.B</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker8'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="fa fa-calendar">
                    </span>
                </span>
        </div>
      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do the browser console give you any error?

Comment: "Please tell me if I have missed to include any css or script tags" - jquery is missing, font-awesome is missing. You can also click on the "Run code sippet" button and you'll see some error messages.

Comment: Also since you're using bootstrap v4, you need to include `tether`.

Comment: I have edited the code and included font-awesome and jquery.

Comment: @MiteshNinja what exactly do I have to include about tether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were so many things wrong with your code. Incorrect css/js files, missing files, incorrect functions. Here's the working version with correct imports.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.2/css/tether.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.2/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  DATE PICKER
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker();
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Replace bootstrap 3.css and .js files with bootstrap 4.css and .js links. And include this above bootstrap.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.2/js/tether.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does the calender open when you try it because it doesn't open with my code. I also am using bootstrap 4 so do I have to remove all those bootstrap 4 imports and include yours.I actually tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: @AkshaySargar did you 'Run code snippet'? It's working perfectly for me. The calendar opens and I can select a date. But keep in mind that you had included `datepicker` library but were using documentaton of `datetimepicker`.

Comment: Ohh sorry I saw you snippet now.Works fine for you.Again but do I have to remove the bootstrap 4 imports and is there any way to work it in bootstrap 4

Comment: @AkshaySargar Yes. Just include the bootrstrap 4 files along with tether.js files. I've edited the answer to include those, and the snippet works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Some of your external cdn resources are out of date, also change `$(...).datetimepicker` to `$(...).datepicker`

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker8').datepicker({
   icons: {
    time: "fa fa-clock-o",
    date: "fa fa-calendar",
    up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
    down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 

<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="form-control-label">D.O.B</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker8'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </div>          
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you..you answer helped as wll.

Comment: @AkshaySargar the `tether.min.js` is no longer required though, just try to include the up-to-date external resources if possible.